# Rails Routing: POST action to destroy content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have an endpoint to destroy an instance of a model through a POST action like the Twitter API does:

```
statuses/destroy/:id
```

How would I define this route in the route file? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I don't know how to do this at all. I know I can use a match route statement but I would think there would be a prettier way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

it may look better if you have other actions in the same resource in rails 3

```
    resources :statuses, :only => [:index, :create]
      collection do
        post 'destroy/:id', :action => :destroy
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do but add this to your `config/routes.rb` should do the trick:

```
match 'statuses/destroy/:id' => 'statuses#destroy', :via => :post
```

(I've found it in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints))